# Android: No Activity found to handle Intent to VIEW an HTTPS website in WebViewCient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android app containing a web view which loads several HTML pages from the assets folder. In some of these HTML files are links to various websites, which I want to open in the user's web browser.

I have had an error report come through Firebase that seems to say that there is no web browser on the user's phone:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://goto.bible/... }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2018)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4689)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
       at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:790)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:932)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1257)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1245)
       at nz.co.conglomo.myapp.WebFragment$onCreateView$1.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebFragment.kt:85)
       at android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewClient.java:77)
       at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(PG:16)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Is this error truly saying the the user has no web browser on their phone, or have I implemented the `WebViewCient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` wrong?

```kotlin
package nz.co.conglomo.myapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.webkit.URLUtil
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import nz.co.conglomo.myapp.databinding.FragmentWebBinding

class WebFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentWebBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = this._binding!!
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        // Get the view
        this._binding = FragmentWebBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        // Set up WebView display and scripting
        this.binding.webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = false
        this.binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        this.binding.webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)

        // Open external URLs in the user's web browser
        this.binding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                if (URLUtil.isAssetUrl(url)) {
                    view.loadUrl(url)
                } else {
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        // Load the web page
        this.binding.webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")

        // Return the view
        return this.binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this error truly saying the the user has no web browser on their phone

It's more saying that the user does not have access to a Web browser. That could be that there is no browser installed. Or, it could be that the device has a browser but the user does not (e.g., restricted user profile).

Comment: I hadn't thought of a restricted user profile. I'll give that a try to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Yes, a restricted profile was the issue - these are a tablet only feature (I was previously only testing on phones). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are handling it the right way, you can override onReceivedError to better handle the crash/error

```
override fun onReceivedError(
                view: WebView,
                errorCode: Int,
                description: String,
                failingUrl: String
            ) {
            }

            override fun onReceivedSslError(
                view: WebView,
                handler: SslErrorHandler,
                error: SslError
            ) {
                val serverCertificate = error.certificate
                if (error.hasError(SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED)) {
                    // Check if Cert-Domain equals the Uri-Domain
                    val certDomain = serverCertificate.issuedTo.cName
                    try {
                        if (certDomain == URL(error.url).host) {
                            handler.proceed()
                        }
                    } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                } else {
                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error)
                }
            }
```